RL10 Injector Plate
Could anyone enlighten me with this puzzle ?
The following frames are screenshots from an P&W RL10 engine's video.
It's actually the top view of Fuel Injector Manifold and the LOX/Injector Domes (???)



The Question is:
a) What are the holes pointed by the RED and YELLOW arrows ?
b) Is there any book/report/guide or photos/diagrams showing more details of the entire part ?
Thank you all.

Can ya link to the video for us?
